# Android: how to delete internal image file

Tags: android, storage, internal

What i want to do: delete an image file from the private internal storage in my app.  I save images in internal storage so they are deleted on app uninstall.

I have successfully created and saved:

```
String imageName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg";
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(imageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 35, fos);
```

an image that i receive through

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

I am able to retrieve the image later for display:

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(imageName);
ByteArrayOutputStream bufStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream outWriter = new DataOutputStream(bufStream);

int ch;
while((ch = fis.read()) != -1)
    outWriter.write(ch);

outWriter.close();
byte[] data = bufStream.toByteArray();
bufStream.close();
fis.close();

imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

I now want to delete this file permanently.  I have tried creating a new file and deleting it, but the file is not found:

```
File file = new File(imageName);
file.delete();
```

I have read on the android developer website that i must open private internal files using the `openFileInput(...)` method which returns an InputStream allowing me to read the contents, which i don't really care about - i just want to delete it.

can anyone point me in the right direction for deleting a file which is stored in internal storage?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Erg, I found the answer myself.  Simple answer too :(

All you have to do is call the `deleteFile(imageName)` method.

```
if(activity.deleteFile(imageName))
    Log.i(TAG, "Image deleted.");
```

Done!

Comment: This does not work at all.  Image still remains in the gallery.  File is flagged correctly as existing, and then I am using your line on the same file, but when I go back to the gallery, it is still there.

Comment: @Bisclavret are you sure the file is saved to internal app storage?

Comment: I am using a different method now, but it may have been because I did not have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions active in the Manifest.  Thank you for your response and I hope this helps someone else.