# Deleting file from private storage on android

Tags: android, file

I'm trying to delete a file that I earlier created in my android app. 
The problem I'm having is that the file won't go away. Even though everything seems to work.

I've looked at several post here on stackoverflow, but still not solution. The garbage collections was one of the hints I've found.

```
System.gc();
System.out.println("Exists: "+file.exists());
System.out.println("Read: "+file.canRead());
System.out.println("Write: "+file.canWrite());
System.out.println("Deleting: " + file);
boolean r = file.delete();
System.out.println("Result of deletion: "+r);
System.gc();
```

And the result in the log

```
Exists: true
Read: true
Write: true
Deleting: data/data/no.ntnu.kpro.app/files/kprothales/XOMessage/8
Result of deletion: true
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why it isn't removed?

EDIT:
Lucifer: Yeah, I have set WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest. 
ShineDown: No, it is just a file without an extension. For now it is containing xml, but this is going to change over time, hence why I have not called it .xml. Could this be a problem?
chintan khetiya: I believe this line is allready included in the code above.

Comment: have you given FILE permission in manifest ?

Comment: Is that a folder? we cant delete it if there are more file present in it.In that case, first delete all inner files.

Comment: boolean deleted = mypath.delete(); // mypath is your path which you want to delet

Comment: Answered the questions in an edit. :)

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451896/android-how-to-delete-internal-image-file

Answer (score 1):

check the answer here:

[Android: how to delete internal image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451896/android-how-to-delete-internal-image-file)

which is basically suggesting to call deleteFile:

if(activity.deleteFile(imageName))
    Log.i(TAG, "Image deleted.");

Comment: Although I appreciate your answer, this question have been dead for almost an year. I really hope this solved the problem but have not way of testing it atm(silly me for not including a simple error generating snipplet). As a sidenote: I really feel android should comply to the docs regarding `delete` method, and once it returns `true` the file(regardless of type) should be deleted. I dont know if you have tried deleting files without fileextensions, but I suspect that may be the error in my case. If not, good for your for finding the error.

Comment: Anyways, +1 for you. Just for finding a solution and trying to solve my. Appreciate it. :)
I would accept the answer if I had a way of testing the solution, but the code has been delivered to the custormers, and is beyond my reach.